# ebpf verifier - failed to find kernel BTF type ID

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I am trying to follow the `Learning eBPF` book by Liz Rice along with code samples at https://github.com/lizrice/learning-ebpf. I have problem with [chapter 7 example - hello.bpf.c](https://github.com/lizrice/learning-ebpf/blob/main/chapter7/hello.bpf.c). The code builds but at runtime the verifier fails it.

```
# ./hello 
libbpf: prog 'fentry_execve': failed to find kernel BTF type ID of 'execve': -3
libbpf: prog 'fentry_execve': failed to prepare load attributes: -3
libbpf: prog 'fentry_execve': failed to load: -3
libbpf: failed to load object 'hello_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'hello_bpf': -3
processed 54 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 4 peak_states 4 mark_read 4
```

I commented out the `fentry/do_execve` section, compiled and ran again. This time I see this error.

```
libbpf: prog 'kprobe_do_execve': failed to create kprobe 'do_execve+0x0' perf event: No such file or directory
libbpf: prog 'kprobe_do_execve': failed to auto-attach: -2
Failed to attach BPF skeleton: -2
```

Now the `do_execve` function does exist, as I see it in kernel sources (unless I have the version wrong). So this error due the possibility that this function `do_execve` might have actually been inlined during compilation?

I did not build that kernel. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (`5.15.0-88-generic #98~20.04.1-Ubuntu`).

clang & bpftool versions -

```
$ clang -v
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Candidate multilib: x32;@mx32
Selected multilib: .;@m64

# bpftool version
bpftool v7.3.0
using libbpf v1.3
features: libbfd
```

PS: I also see it is not listed by `bpftrace`

```
$ sudo bpftrace -l "*execve*"
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_execve
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_exit_execve
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_execveat
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_exit_execveat
kprobe:audit_log_execve_info
kprobe:bprm_execve
kprobe:do_execveat_common.isra.0
kprobe:__ia32_sys_execve
kprobe:__ia32_sys_execveat
kprobe:__ia32_compat_sys_execve
kprobe:__ia32_compat_sys_execveat
kprobe:__x64_compat_sys_execveat
kprobe:__x64_sys_execveat
kprobe:__x64_sys_execve
kprobe:__x64_compat_sys_execve
kprobe:kernel_execve
```